# how to remove white space from both side?

Tags: html, css

I want to remove white space which is colored black on image from both side

[image]

to remove this white space from header i add margin-left:-10px

```
.site-header-main {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    padding: 44px 0 22px;
    padding: 4.4rem 0 2.2rem;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

After adding this I successfully removed white space from the left side but a grey color space comes on right side image here

[image]

Comment: website  http://chiku.pe.hu/

Comment: please put a link so we can have a look.

Comment: Please Check the parent tag i think the issue is not with the margin parent tag is having padding left and right so fix that.

Comment: @Shan Khaliq  website is  http://chiku.pe.hu/

Comment: @charchit please check the answer below and select it if this do the trick for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the `margin: -10;` you put in the css and add this to it.

```
.site-header-main .container {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

The container class is having a margin of 3.3em from both left and right. so this will fix this glitch.

if You want to remove this from the whole site try this

```
body .container {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: perfect man! i want to remove this padding from whole site so i add padding:0px; in .container but there is still some white space on site content div image here http://s18.postimg.org/xnyy0wsyh/wwwwwwww.jpg

Comment: To remove the padding from site content i add .site-content {
    padding: 0;
} but still some space left

Comment: @charchit i have updated the answer try that.

Comment: Please select the answer as you think your problem solved ;-)